# How to process HTTP POST request in Django without CSRF token

Tags: django, post, amazon-web-services, http-post, amazon-sns

I am using Amazon SNS to receive push messages on my HTTP/HTTPS endpoint. The endpoint application is written in Django. To receive notifications on the endpoint (web app), the HTTP/HTTPS endpoint needs to be subscribed to a topic.

Once subscribed, the Amazon SNS sends an HTTP POST request to the specified url where one needs to confirm the subscription by retrieving the parameters in the headers of the HTTP POST request.

I tried this using Google Chrome extension `Postman` by sending a POST request on my url but it gives a `CSRF token error`.

My problem is when the Amzaon SNS sends the confirmation for subscription, how can it send the CSRF token in the POST request so that I can process the request and retrieve the required information?

Documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try making the post request method csrf exempt.

```
@csrf_exempt
def post(self, request):
    ...
    return ...
```

Also try clearing the cookies.

Comment: make sure that you add  ---- from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt ----
in the file as well